# Addition of mysql fields

Tags: php, mysql

For instance, all my users have a coins field. I want to be able to collaborate all the coins gained between all the users but unsure of how to query it.

this is my current query, i have tried using this query.

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT `coins` FROM `users` WHERE `coins` > 0");
        echo mysql_result($query, 0);
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(coins) as sum FROM users where coins > 0`..

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT SUM(coins) FROM users` should work.

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(coins) as Total_Coins from users
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [SUM() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
SELECT SUM(`coins`) AS `total` FROM `users` WHERE `coins` > 0
```